# Make install error: You do not appear to have the sources for the x-y-z kernel installed

Tags: server, kernel, software-installation, source

I am trying to install Dahdi on my newly installed machine, when I do a `make install` on the latest version, I get error:

```
You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.5.0-25-generic kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-generic
```

That should set you up.

Dahi is also available from the Ubuntu repositories, and can be eaasily installed from the Software Center.

Comment: didnt work... linux-source is already the newest version.

Comment: Make sure you also have the `linux-headers-generic` package.

Comment: i installed that package and still saying You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.5.0-25-generic kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
 when i do a make

Comment: Hm..., not sure why it refuses to work. By the way, [Dadhi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dahdi) is apparently available in the repositories.